# DotNetOpenAuth request login from provider

Tags: .net, dotnetopenauth

How can I force a user to login to his provider before he is redirected back (by adding his username and password at the provider he is redirected to)?

Because now if the user is already logged in his Google Account let's say dotnetopenauth automatically connects him with that account.

Is there a property in dotnetauth that forces a user to login again to his provider before redirected back?

Answer (score 2):

The OpenID PAPE extension (in DotNetOpenAuth it's called PolicyRequest) allows an RP to *request* that the OP re-authenticate the user.  But ultimately there is no way to force it.  Here's how you submit the request:

```
var pape = new PolicyRequest();
pape.MaximumAuthenticationAge = TimeSpan.Zero;
request.AddExtension(pape);
request.RedirectToProvider();
```

If the OP supports the above request, they will usually include a PAPE response, which you can retrieve and check like this:

```
var papeResponse = response.GetExtension<PolicyResponse>();
if (papeResponse != null && papeResponse.AuthenticationTimeUtc.HasValue && (DateTime.UtcNow - papeResponse.AuthenticationTimeUtc.Value) < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)) {
     // Probably re-authenticated the user
}
```

You may need to adjust the above check slightly.  Also keep in mind that the OP may lie about it.  So if there is a legal or other significant requirement that OPs reauthenticate the user, you should have a business contract with that OP set up to provide that assurance -- PAPE by itself means very little.  And most OPs don't support it.